# ng-include how to retain content of already included template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Firstly ***the code***

```
<div ng-repeat="item in tabs" ng-if="tabIndex == item.name" ng-include="item.view"></div>
```

I have a ***json of tabs*** as

```
$scope.tabs = [
            {
                "name" : "Item1",
                "display" : "<span class='fa fa-cubes'></span> Localhost",
                "view" : "views/_item.html",
                "active" : 0
            }{
                "name" : "Item1",
                "display" : "<span class='fa fa-cubes'></span> Localhost",
                "view" : "views/_item.html",
                "active" : 0
            }

        ];
```

The tabs.view is repeated, that's why when the ng-repeat run the ng-include calls the same link. This is fine for me. And it calles the template once, that is pefect for me too.

Now the problem
This is ***the _item.html page***

```
<textarea>value</textarea>
```

Well both tabs calling the same page, when run display me textarea with content as 'value'. But when i edit the content in any one of tab and switch to other, and come back to the same tab, i find the textarea content is resetted to value.

How to avoid that?
I don't want to create a special directive for that, if there is any other solution please suggest.

To clarify to the point, **I want ng-include to not refresh the template once its loaded in the div**.

Comment: You probably need to set an `ng-model` on the textarea. You may be able to do this dynamically but that would require a custom directive

Comment: doesn't seems how ng-model will work, can you elaborate?, or do you think i need to provide more detail? Its simple textarea, when i change its content i want the content to remain but not change on tab change. Thanks .. tried and it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem lies with your use of **ng-if**.*

The directive ng-if uses the $animate service which is useful for animations from html to html without a controller.js call. *Possible examples* to use ng-if will be a text box view based on selection of a radio button or checkbox. [Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

I recommended you use $scope variables to retain the previous values. and use [**ng-show**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) instead of ng-if to provide animation for variables item.view

[**ng-if**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) vs [**ng-show**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I replace ng-if to ng-show and it worked. :)

Comment: Welcome. Happy coding :)